# How addItem to ArrayList in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, arraylist

I have some arrays:

```
var dataProvider:IList = new ArrayList();
var labelArr:Array = [IT, Business, Doctor, Teacher, Engineer, IT, Business, Doctor, Teacher, Engineer];
var valueArr:Array = [50,46,64,85,98,37,58,48,14,28];
```

How dataArr.addItem() from two arrays to arrayList with similar below result data:

```
dataProvider = ([
           {data:[
               {label:'IT', value: 50},
               {label:'Business', value: 46},
               {label:'Doctor', value: 64},
               {label:'Teacher', value: 85},
               {label:'Engineer', value: 98} ]},
           {data:[
               {label:'IT', value: 37},
               {label:'Business', value: 58},
               {label:'Doctor', value: 48},
               {label:'Teacher', value: 14},
               {label:'Engineer', value: 28} ]}
           ]);
```

I want above result to get data array for draw

Comment: Can you clarify and show what you have tried?

Comment: ok, you can review my last edited

Comment: Well what I see is: an array having two objects, each object having a data entry and each data entry is an array having 5 objects each having label and value entries. So... 1) you can use ordinary array for this. 2) It has only one entry... Use for loops. What is the question anyway? Try coding something, then if it does not work, show here, I will try to fix it.

Comment: thanks u, currently i was fixed this question